# Just rebuild a server that was receive event ID 467

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, domaincontroller

I had a server (AD DC, 2008r2) a few weeks ago that was giving error event ID 467

---

Log Name:      Directory Service
Source:        NTDS ISAM
Date:          5/3/2013 9:46:10 AM
Event ID:      467
Task Category: Database Corruption
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      ******
Description:
NTDS (568) NTDSA: Database C:\Windows\NTDS\ntds.dit: Index DRA_USN_index of table datatable is corrupted (0).

---

I demoted the DC and rebuilt it from scratch, renamed it and re-added it as a different DC, but now getting these errors again :( after a few weeks.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the AD database gets corrupted. Did you try running esentutl against it? See some comments about this type of problem at [www.eventid.net](http://www.eventid.net/display-eventid-467-source-NTDS%20ISAM-eventno-5457-phase-1.htm) - it mentions a hotfix available for 2008. Since it happened twice so far, maybe you have a hardware issue or maybe that hotfix will take care of it.